# Unknown Column in Where Clause : Mysql Update Query

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mariadb

This is my update query :

```
update grade 
  set grade='A'
where (select assignment*0.3+midExam*0.35+finalExam*0.35 as FINALSCORE 
       from taking) >= 85 
  and taking.student_id = grade.student_id 
  and taking.subject_id = grade.subject-id;
```

and the result is below

> Unknown column 'taking.student_id' in 'where clause'

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table `taking` is inside a  subquery then is not visible outside the subquery

for your need you should use an update with join

```
update grade 
INNER JOIN taking ON taking.student_id=grade.student_id
       and taking.subject_id=grade.subject_id 
         and taking.assignment*0.3+taking.midExam*0.35+taking.finalExam*0.35 >= 85
set grade='A'
```

for a general solution

you could try adding a case when for each grade

```
update grade 
INNER JOIN taking ON taking.student_id=grade.student_id
       and taking.subject_id=grade.subject_id          
set grade = (case when taking.assignment*0.3+taking.midExam*0.35+taking.finalExam*0.35 >= 85 THEN  'A'
              when taking.assignment*0.3+taking.midExam*0.35+taking.finalExam*0.35 between 60.0 and 84.9 THEN 'B'
              ELSE 'C' END)
```

Comment: i try but the grade become 0

Comment: i'm not in your data   .. and if you have 0 this mean that the error you have seems solved   anyway    ,,  update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result ..  (as tabular text)   .

Comment: I have 2 tables, the first table (taking) contains (student_id, subject_id, assignment, midExam, finalExam), and the second table (grade) contains (student_id, subject_id, and grade). example assignment value, midExam, finalExam adalag (88.00, 67.00, 88.09). and the command to be done is to calculate all values (assignment*0.3+midExam*0.35+finalExam*0.35) to be between A,B,C,D with A= >85, B= 85>70, C= 60 <70, D= 55<- 60, E=<55

Comment: update grade set grade='A' where (select assignment*0.3+midExam*0.35+finalExam*0.35 as FINALSCORE from taking where student_id=990 and subject_id=110) >= 85 and student_id=990 and subject_id=110; this is an example code given by the lecturer, but I have 40 student data and 10 subject_id, I'm looking for a code that works for the whole,

Comment: @NATALIA   ...as in my first comment I'm not in you data and in your mind and  SO is not a coding service  ..or   a tutoring service for programmer. SO  is question/answer  site  ..  you posted  a question about a syntax error and I  have answer to your question then   . if you, once revolved the first problem, have others problem you should post  new questions  specifically documented .. and if the answer  have solve you original question  you should mark as accepted the right.. answer

Comment: @NATALIA   I have update  the answer  adding a solution for all grades  .. let me know if this can help you or eventually comment me the link for a new question ..

Comment: already try @scaisEdge but there an eror You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '> 85
set grade = (case when taking.assignment*0.3+taking.midExam*0.35+taking....' at line 4

Comment: in the first query or in the second one  (the new added ) ??

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '> 85 set grade = (case when taking.assignment*0.3+taking.midExam*0.35+taking....' at line 4

Comment: i'm sorry, i dont know how to use this web, because this is the first time i try this web